# "Permission denied" for a custom content filter in Postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix, permissions

I've created a simple content filter as a python script, for Postfix:

```
$ ls -al /home/main_user/test1.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vmail2 nobody /home/main_user/test1.py
```

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf` I have this:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd 
  -o content_filter=filter1:dummy

# [........................]

filter1    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
    flags=Rq user=vmail2 null_sender=
    argv=/home/main_user/test1.py -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Error in the logs of Postfix:

```
fatal: pipe_command: execvp /home/main_user/test1.py Permission denied
```

**vmail2** - is a user with no home directory. I've created it specifically for this task:

```
$ id vmail2
uid=5002(vmail2) gid=5002(vmail2) groups=5002(vmail2)
```

Why does it fail and how to fix it?

update1:

Permission of the "home":

```
$ ls -ald ~
drwx------ 12 main_user main_user 4096  /home/main_user
```

Comment: What are the perms of /home/main_user, and is SELinux active?

Comment: @davidgo haven't I shown the permssions in my questions?

Comment: @davidgo SE Linux isn't active

Comment: You showed the permission of the file, bit not the directory it is in. They can be different.

Comment: @davidgo updated

Comment: Permissions on homedir seem wrong to me. As it stands vmail2 can't open that directory- try "chmod 755 /home/main_user" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @davidgo then other users will also be able to access it, that's also wrong

Comment: Its not clear what you are wanting. You can change the location of the script, or grant the user access to the parent directory or not have the script work. Those are the choices.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much says it all.

> fatal: pipe_command: execvp /home/main_user/test1.py Permission denied

the user `vmail2` doesn't have access to `/home/main_user`

I would probably `chown :vmail2 /home/main_user; chmod g+rx /home/main_user` and make sure `test1.py` has at least group-read and group-execute permissions for the `vmail2` group as well

Comment: then other users will also be able to access `/home/main_user`, that's also wrong